# Connected categories and connected limits

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category together with an equivalence relation $∼$ on the objects by $x ∼ y$ whenever there is a morphism $f: x \to y$.

1. What does $(Ob(C)/∼) \cong 1$ mean? What kind of isomorphism is this?
2. What does it mean for a category to have all small connected limits?

Comment: A fun theorem, that may perhaps come up, is the following: a category, $\mathcal{C}$, is **connected**, as spelled out by Ben, if and only if $\mathbf{Cat}(\mathcal{C},-)$ preserves coproducts.

Comment: It's an isomorphism of sets.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, note that this relation is in general not symmetric, so we have to take the equivalence relation generated by this relation. That is, $x\sim y$ if and only if there is a zigzag of morphisms $x\to x_1\leftarrow x_2\to \dots  \leftarrow x_n \to y$ in $C$. Therefore, we can think of an equivalence class as a connected component of $C$; it's a bunch of objects which can be joined by a zigzag of morphisms. Consequently, if $\mathrm{Ob}(C)/{\sim} \cong 1$, meaning that there is precisely one equivalence class, it makes sense to call $C$ *connected*: There exists an object of $C$ and each pair of objects can be connected through a zigzag of morphisms.

Now, a connected limit is one where the indexing category is connected and a category has all connected limits if all such connected limits exist.

Comment: To make it a bit more explicit, $\text{Ob}(C)/{\sim} \cong 1$ doesn't just imply $C$ is connected but is equivalent to $C$ being connected, i.e. $\text{Ob}(C)/{\sim} \cong 1$ can be taken as a definition of being connected. A simple consequence of either your or my definition of connected, that's nevertheless worth pointing out, is that the empty category is *not* connected.

Comment: Dear @DerekElkins, do you think I should edit the post to make clear that I want to include inhabited in the definition? (Actually, I was implicitly assuming that $\mathrm{Ob}(C)/{\sim}\cong1$ is the OP's definition of $C$ being connected and I was only trying to motivate this.)

Comment: I think that's a reasonable assumption. There is a small possibility that someone reading your answer without that context may take you as merely saying $\text{Ob}(C)/{\sim}\cong 1$ implies connected, though I do think your wording strongly suggests you are making a definition. I don't think you should explicitly add "inhabited" to the definition; it's already implied. This is an example of [too simple to be simple](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple), and one's reaction might be that the empty case is or should be included which is false but perhaps not obviously so.

Comment: You're probably right, @DerekElkins. I edited the post accordingly. Thanks for noting this and for reminding me of this nLab-entry.